# Disabling multiple HTML buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple buttons `name="angka"` and `id="angka"`:

```
<input type="button" name="angka" id="angka" value="1" style="width:15px" onclick="insert(1)">
<input type="button" name="angka" id="angka" value="2" style="width:15px" onclick="insert(2)">
<input type="button" name="angka" id="angka" value="3" style="width:15px" onclick="insert(3)">
```

`onLoadPage` event I try to disabled them with the below code.

```
document.getElementById("operator").disabled = true; 
document.getElementsByName("operator").disabled = true;
```

But the result is that only the first button is disabled, the other buttons are still enabled.

How to disable the buttons with JavaScript without making unique names or ids?

solve with

```
`var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].disabled =true;
}`
```

Comment: First problem: each of your buttons should have a different id.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, Use class instead of ID.

Comment: Also, why would you disable them onloadpage? Just disable them in the html.

Comment: could i disabled that button with class attribute? hows?

Comment: @arbitter i have requirement to change state the button based on user action. so i need disabled that things whenever user want it(not only at begining).

Comment: @ozrent lets say i have diferent id. i need to grouping the buttons so when i call one method the state of group button will change. How to do that?

Comment: @guurnita: common method of grouping different HTML element is using `class`. So, as already said, instead `id="angka"` use `class="angka"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Red said: Use class instead of ID

```
<input type="button" name="angka" class="angka" value="1" style="width:15px" onclick="insert(1)">
```

After that, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("angka");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

I'm not sure getElementsByClassName() is cross-browser, so take care. However, jQuery is good at this, so you could use that and make your life more simple.

**EDIT**

jQuery (untested) example for that:

```
$('input.angka').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. You can't set the attribute of the entire array at once, you have to loop through it and handle each element individually.

Comment: some crumbs from me too: `for` with `total` where `var total = elems.length;` works faster then count it each loop